# What is the term for the sections of a Subsection?

Tags: terminology

I have been looking to write up some information about a fictional species and I understand to a point some of the legislative writing. But I never understood a few terms.

Example:

"3.2.5.4"

First Digit, 3 — I understand that the first Digit in the series represents the main section to a article of legislation (for example).

Second Digit, 2 — Also undstand that the second Digit represents a Subsection within the main section.

Third and Fourth Digits, 5/4 — This is where I am stuck on because I can't remember the term.

---

My Question:

What is the term used for any Digit after the subsection?

Comment: Are you thinking of a [paragraph](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paragraph)?

Comment: I actually might be thinking of subsubsections, but I'm not sure.

Comment: They are just subsections.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to have a hierarchy consisting of some or all of :

- Part
- Chapter
- Section
- Subsection
- Subsubsection
- Paragraph

The first two aren't generally used in shorter works, and divisions below *subsection* are generally used in niche applications such as legal writing. *Subparagraph* is rarer still. The sequence is almost always the same. Here's a list of [how they're used in LaTeX](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure). I chose this link because it includes a bit of discussion about what type of documents use which divisions. I've seen *subsubsubsection* used in all seriousness, but that's not standard.

Note that *subsubsection* is jargon that's only really used when "subsection of subsection *x*" doesn't work, but "paragraph *y* of subsection *x*" isn't appropriate either. There isn't (so far as I know) a term for a more general subdivision of a subsection, except that in certain contexts *paragraph* doesn't have its everyday meaning.